# iOS: RefreshControl + large title doesn't work well in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, pull-to-refresh

I have UIViewController with NavigationBar that is a part of UITabController.

Inside UIViewController I have only UITableView.

NavigationBar is transparent and blurred.

TableView top constraint is to superview, so when I scroll content it goes behind navigation bar.

I have large titles enabled:

Problem:

loadData data triggered immediately when I start to scroll down.
Right after I scroll few pixels down.

All works fine if I remove largeTitles,
but with large titles it feels like refreshControl already at position when it ready to trigger .valueChanged

Also it works fine if to remove tab bar and load navigationController directly as root. But I need tabbar.

Full code:

```
@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
        let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        self.window = window
        
        window.rootViewController = TabBarController()
        
        return true
    }
}

class TabBarController: UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
        navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        
        viewControllers = [navigationController]
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private let tableView = UITableView()
    
    private let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        navigationItem.title = "Test"
        
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loadData), for: .valueChanged)
    }
    
    @objc func loadData() {
        print("loadData triggered")
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0) {
            self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell: UITableViewCell
        if let defaultCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "defaultCell") {
            cell = defaultCell
        } else {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "defaultCell")
        }
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Test"
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        10
    }
}
```

**BUT**

All works fine if it's from StoryBoard:
[image]

Comment: I feel that I read the same topic a few hours ago.

Comment: @ElTomato I did post that an hour ago. But then deleted and prepared code so it's clear what I'm doing and prepared a code that is easy to try